# How to write unittest for myexception and raise?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

how to writing unit tests for exception and raise? For example I have

someFoo.py

```py
class MyExc(Exception):
  """
  my exc
  """
  pass

def foo(a,b,c):
  raise MyExc

def foo1(a,b):
  assert a==b, 'a==b!!'
```

tests.py

```py
from someFoo import foo,foo1
import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  pass
```

and I can't find good solution for this

Comment: Please update your question with the not good solutions you found, plus the reasons they are not good.

Comment: Also, `raise a==b, 'a==b!!'` will give you the error `TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException`, so you probably don't want to do that. You can't use any object with `raise`; it has to be an exception object.

Comment: sorry my bad in the second example of course

```assert ```